# How are you guys testing complex react native applications?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, detox

I am the only one that feels that creating usefull tests for complex react native applications is actually impossible?

How are you guys testing apps that have a lot of native dependencies?

If i try to use jest with enzyme or react native testing library, I end up using jest.mock() to mock most of my components logic to the point that tests actually feel useless. Most of the native components just feel impossible to mock and I have to spend most of my time figuring out how to mock native libraries instead of writing tests.

I have some tests using detox that are usefull, but they take toooo long to run, and most of the time they are super flaky and slow, especially in CI/CD like bitrise, which i found to be the best option to use with detox.

Detox do not work with web views and some important components like Alerts. Also setting up mocking is a pain in the ass.

I haven't found any content online that teaches how to test on real react native applications.

I found that using react testing library or enzyme with react web applications is much easier, and tests make much more sense.

Are people actually not testing in react native?

How do i make sure things arent going to break without manual QA every time i am deploying a new version?

This is not suposed to be a rant, I just want the opinion of people with complex production apps, because I am desperate and in need for love.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Appium (Python or node) + AWS Device Farm for e2e testing. It can be quite painful to set it up and it needs some time too, but it saves us a lot of time on every release. To be able to test in parallel on so many devices is really nice.

Since I'm also using bitrise, I can tell you the integration is quite nice. I have written a short article on medium about my experiences:
https://medium.com/horizon-alpha/optimizing-react-native-development-process-with-bitbucket-and-bitrise-io-d0aebe641db8

You could give it a try.